# getParcelable returns null even if passed object is no null

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I want to pass a parcelable object to an activity to another one. 
So I implemented a parcelable class to accomplish this. 
And I coded:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mainactivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Object[] object = new Object();
intent.putExtra("Object ", object);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in the second activity I coded:

```
Object[] object = (Object[]) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("object");
```

When I pass the object to Intent, it's not null. 
While, when I get it in the second Activity is null. 
Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Change this:

```
Object object = (Object) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("object");
```

To this:

```
Object object = getIntent().getExtras().get("Object");
```

`getParcelable` should only be used if you are using `putParcelable` or inserting a `Parcelable` object using `putExtra` in the sending part of code.

P.S. also mind the difference of key-name **Object** and **object**

Comment: did you fix the **O** difference in key?

Comment: I noticed that you updated your question using array. You can't play with arrays in simple terms. Try implementing Parcelable to your object and then put parcelableArray in bundle

Comment: I fixed it. 
I noted that the problem is the casting. I get a parcelable object but it's not possible to cast it into my Array Object.
I'm working on it now.

Comment: I just parsed each Parcelable array element in a Object array one and all works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use in the caller:

```
Intent i = new Intent(EditActivity.this, ViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("myObj", p);
startActivity(i);
```

In the receiver:

```
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
Person p = (Person) b.getParcelable("myObject");
```

Hope this help you

Comment: I saw somewhere similar like your answer that- `i.putExtra("return-data", p);` and in receiver `b.getParcelable("data");` and its working. How it can be possible where two keys are not the same ? I wonder about it.